# Difference between nginx installed from source and nginx install as package?

Tags: nginx, installation

What all are the differences between install nginx from source and  install as package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to define "all differences" would be near impossible because every OS package is built differently. However, with that said...

1) Package installs are pre-built with their own options configured which also gets installed wherever they decided to put that installation once it's installed.

2) With the source, you are able to define what is built, where it should be installed, etc...

So if you are going to install via a package, you are basically forced into whatever options they set. Unless of course you decide to take their package and then re-package it to fit your requirements. But that would pretty much be a pointless as you'd be better off just installing from source at that point.

Most if not all packages also comes not only with a simple install but a simple way to uninstall the software. Where-as if you compiled and installed via source then you'll need to manually remove the installation if you no longer need it on your machine.